# How to preserve yanked text in buffer after pasting over selection in Visual mode using VSCode Vim extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keymapping, vscodevim

I am using the Vim extension in Visual Studio Code and I'm facing an issue with the
buffer behavior. When I yank some text and then paste it over a selection in visual
mode, the yanked text gets replaced in the buffer with the text that was
overwritten. This is not the behavior I want.

In Neovim, I can use the black hole register to prevent the overwritten text from
replacing the yanked text in the buffer. The command looks something like this in my
Neovim configuration:

`vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('v', 'p', '"_dP', {noremap = true})`

This command maps  p  in visual mode to  "_dP , which deletes the selected text into
the black hole register and then pastes the yanked text. This way, the yanked text
remains in the buffer even after pasting.

I would like to replicate this behavior in Visual Studio Code using the VSCode Vim
extension. How can I achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.